# My web scraped code currently works, I want to be more specific, can I choose what data to scrape by telling it what specific header that is above it?

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

Here is my current code which works great, it extracts all the `<li>` from the specific div.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from project.items import QualificationItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
name = 'usw'
allowed_domains = ['http://international.southwales.ac.uk']
start_urls = ['http://international.southwales.ac.uk/countries']

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    links = []
    xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/a/@href'
    link = [ 'http://international.southwales.ac.uk' + x for x in hxs.select(xpath).extract()]
    links.extend(link)

    for link in links:
        yield Request(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'},callback=self.parse_linkpage,dont_filter=True)

def parse_linkpage(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = QualificationItem()
    result = hxs.select('/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/ul[*]/li/text()').extract()
    item ['Qualification'] = result
    return item
```

I want this code to be more specific, If you look at this webpage http://eu.southwales.ac.uk/country/cyprus/en/ and look at the html, I want to extract the undergraduate entry requirements so the specific data that I want to extract is the \ul\li's underneath the header `<h4>Undergraduate Entry Requirements</h4>`. I could just use xpath but it changes and moves for different country pages, this is why I'm asking whether it is possbile to extract it just by choosing what header that is above it.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @adamretter's answer is to use `following-sibling`

```
//h4[normalize-space(.)="Undergraduate Entry Requirements"]
 /following-sibling::ul[1]
```

Also, I see a few things in your code:

- `allowed_domains` should contain domain names, not URLs
- it's safer to use `urlparse.urljoin()` to build full URLs (you already include `urljoin` so might as well use it)
- there's no real need to use a temporary `links` list in your `parse` method

So you spider code becomes:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from project.items import QualificationItem
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from urlparse import urljoin


USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0'

class recursiveSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'usw'
    allowed_domains = ['international.southwales.ac.uk']
    start_urls = ['http://international.southwales.ac.uk/countries']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/ul/li/a/@href'
        for link in hxs.select(xpath).extract():
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, link),
                          headers={'User-Agent': USER_AGENT},
                          callback=self.parse_linkpage,
                          dont_filter=True)

    def parse_linkpage(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = QualificationItem()
        xpath = """
                //h4[normalize-space(.)="Undergraduate Entry Requirements"]
                 /following-sibling::ul[1]/li/text()
                """
        item['Qualification'] = hxs.select(xpath).extract()
        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can just modify your XPath to find the first `ul` that follows the `h4` that you are interested in e.g. Undergraduate Entry Requirements. For example:

```
//ul[preceding-sibling::h4[text() = "Undergraduate Entry Requirements"]][1]
```

The key here is the `preceding-sibling` axis.